# How to preserve space character between replacement tags in i18next translation string

Tags: reactjs, i18next, react-i18next

I am using v10 of `react-i18next` and the latest `Trans` component to have a translation string with a portion of the sentence bolded.

In the HTML I can insert a `&nbsp;` to ensure there is a space between the `<strong>` block and the rest of the sentence but it gets stripped out in the translation string.

JSX file:

```html
<Trans i18nKey="free_trial_enabled">
  <strong>30 Day Free Trial enabled</strong>&nbsp;for all users
</Trans>
```

JSON translation key/value file:

```
"free_trial_enabled": "<0>30 Day Free Trial enabled</0> for all users",
```

Output HTML:
`<strong>30 Day Free Trial enabled</strong> for all users`

Which looks like: 
'**30 Day Free Trial enabled**for all users'

How can I preserve the `&nbsp;` in the translation string so the space after the `strong` block will be there?

Comment: It works for me: https://codesandbox.io/s/qo18n4vjj, maybe you have some css that removes whitespace?

Answer (score 7):

Thanks @felixmosh!
`white-space: pre-wrap;` fixed the issue.

Answer (score 3):

I am sharing my knowledge here.
Using

```
white-space: pre-wrap;
```

Works all fine. however, in my case, I was not able to use it due to the structure of my text. I needed some text with some anchor in between. In order to get it work, I have to do the following:

```
  "my_string": "<p><Link>Some anchor texr</Link> followed by normal text.</p>",
```

Then, I substitute my translatable string as follows:

```
<Trans
          i18nKey="my_string"
          components={{
            Link: <a target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" href={"https://some_url"}/>
          }}
        />
```

This way works also fine in terms of adding white spaces between anchor text and normal text.

I hope this will be helpful to others as in my case, almost all of scenarios that I end up having to use i18next components are because of needing to show anchors.

Also, in case you need to be able to style your paragraph, you can make a change like this:

```
  "my_string": "<Paragraph><Link>Some anchor texr</Link> followed by normal text.</Paragraph>",
```

Then, in your components declaration:

```
<Trans
          i18nKey="my_string"
          components={{
            Paragraph: <p className={"my-auto"}/>,
            Link: <a target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" href={"https://some_url"}/>
          }}
        />
```